# Juqey addclass is not working?

Tags: jquery, html

On click of "category_filter" class it should add active class when again reclick means it should remove class otherwise no if page reloads also How to resolve this?

Below is my html code,

```html
 <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Fitted bed Sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/fitted-bed-sheet"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Flat bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/flat-bed-sheet"> Flat bed sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Full bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/full-bed-sheets"> Full bed sheets   </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Twin bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twin-bed-sheet"> Twin bed sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Twinxl bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twinxl-bed-sheets"> Twinxl bed sheets   </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Queen bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/queen-bed-sheet"> Queen bed sheet  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="King bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-bed-sheets"> King bed sheets  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Cal king bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/cal-king-bed-sheets"> Cal king bed sheets  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Duvet covers " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/duvet-covers"> Duvet covers  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Bed skirts " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/bed-skirts"> Bed skirts  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Standard Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/standard-pillow-cases"> Standard Pillow cases  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="King Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-pillow-cases"> King Pillow cases  </a> </div>
    <div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Pillow shells " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/pillow-shells"> Pillow shells  </a> </div>
```

Juqey code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.category_filter').click(function(e) {

        $('.category_filter').removeClass('active');

        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: @aleksander It is not working.

Comment: Do you mean jQuery instead of Juqey?

Comment: @C0dekid I dint get u?

Comment: In your title @Mohan

Comment: Oh sorry its jquery

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can use `toggleClass`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.category_filter').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.category_filter').removeClass('active');
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No it is not adding.